# Vim's "hit-enter" mode. Using ; of `:map ; :` without clearing displayed contents.

Tags: vim

Do any maps work from `hit-enter` mode? Reading `:help hit-enter`, it seems the only way to continue writing commands without redrawing clearing the screen, is to start a command with `:`.

But there we read:

```
-> Press ':' or any other Normal mode command character to start that command.
```

Why doesn't `nnoremap ; :` apply? (What are "other Normal mode command character[s]"?) I'd like to quickly start a new command without losing the displayed contents from the previous command. I'd also like to be able to use the `leader` key without losing the displayed contents.

For instance, try `;ls<Ret>`, then `;` or your `<leader>` key.

It's not that bad, I can use `:` after, just wondering if I could get more control in `hit-enter-mode`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
nnoremap gb :ls<CR>:b<Space>
```

Is the "canonical" way to do what you want.

Comment: Note that the `<Space>` is not necessary but more readable in my opinion.

Comment: I like the `<Space>` in case a plug-in complains about trailing white-space. Do you have a mapping for a combo with `:ls!`? I'm considering having one mapping with `:ls!<CR>:b<Space>`, and if I really need to `bd` or `bw`, I can just backspace and type the extra character.

Comment: What about `gB`? If you are curious about what can be done without much plugins take a look at [my config](https://github.com/romainl/dotvim).